# DOMpdf with laravel is changing the HTML layout white it is working fine with browser tab

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am using dom PDF to convert HTML to PDF file. My HTML has heavy css like postition and flex. somehow I manage to remove flex. My problem is when I export my html to pdf in pdf layout of html get change but it is showing perfactly fine if I open that html in my browser I am adding an image referance to show,

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .gridItem {
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: move;
            transition: transform .09s ease-in;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .gridItem-circle {
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #444;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #fff;
            height: 60%;
            width: 60%;
        }
        .gridItem-seat {
            border: 1px solid #444;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border-radius: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            height: 33px;
            width: 33px;
        }

        .gridItem-circleLabel {
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 21px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            color: #8c8c8c;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 0 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="gridItem ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="circle22" style="top: 239px; left: 514px; width: 208px; height: 208px; visibility: visible; position: relative; z-index: 999999;">
            <div class="gridItem-table gridItem-circle" style="z-index: -1">
                <div class="gridItem-circleLabel">
                    Makwana Family
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(0deg) translate(64px) rotate(-0deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(45deg) translate(64px) rotate(-45deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(90deg) translate(64px) rotate(-90deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(135deg) translate(64px) rotate(-135deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(180deg) translate(64px) rotate(-180deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(225deg) translate(64px) rotate(-225deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(270deg) translate(64px) rotate(-270deg);"></div>
            <div class="gridItem-seat ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 17.5px); left: calc(50% - 17.5px); z-index: -1; transform: rotate(315deg) translate(64px) rotate(-315deg);"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I can help you.

You should set CSS according to pdf instead of your web browser view

Please refer to the following link for your HTML debugging
http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php

Thanks

Comment: I have checked this site before but didn't get any idea. like how can I debug my html. I have copy past my html code and click submit button but it open new tab nothing is happaning.

Comment: And also how can I design CSS according to pdf. I mean there is no way to check CSS like we check in browser by clicking on inspect element.

Comment: You have to debug with change CSS and submit every time to see the CSS effect. It looks tricky but it's working

Comment: You can't inspect that changes on  inspect element of web browser